# Get currency values from a string

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm coding a pretty basic app with java in netbeans for an assessment. It's meant to be an online shop that adds the user's purchases to a text area as a summary. 2 combo boxes let the user choose the product and the quantity so an example summary shows as "Apples £1.25 x 3."
I've got the coding for that done but now I need to parse the price and the quantity from the string, multiplying them and then adding any other orders together so that a label can display the order total. This is where I'm struggling.

Here's the string I'm working with:

OrderSummary_txt.append((String)Items_cmbo.getSelectedItem() + " x " + (String)Quantity_cmbo.getSelectedItem() + "\n");

I think I need to use indexOf("£") to get started but after that I get lost. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any chance to grab the individual values before they are being converted to a String? Otherwise this sounds like a usecase for a regular expression with capture groups.

Comment: You'd make this a lot easier if you had `ComboBoxModel<Product>`. You could then just grab the price directly out of the selected item.

Comment: The items list is pretty small so I could delcare global variables for the individual prices, that'll only work because there are only 4 items in the list though. Right now the items in the combo box is both the item and the price together.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure not to parse the text, use the calculation based on a datamodel. So based on the selected products and amounts you will get a model like:

```
List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
orders.add(order1);

public class Order  {
    Product product;
    int amount;
    constructor/ getter/setters ommitted
}
```

Then create the summery by foreach over the orders. and create the total amount by doing the same

```
String summary = "";
int total = 0;
for (Order order : orders) {
      summary += order.getProduct().getDescription() + "\n";
      total += (order.getAmount() * order.getProduct().getPrice());
}
summary += "Total price " + total;
```

put summary in your textArea